# Device interface's IP Address

Tags: interface, ip

[Question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYv9j.png)

Can anyone tell me how to solve the question iv) ? I don't really understand what the question is looking for. What does it mean by device interface's ip address?

Answer (score 0):

Your device may have several network interfaces. Those can correspond to real devices (NICs) or be virtual.

In order to be usable (i.e. initiate or listen for connections), each interface should have an IP address. Usually there will be one IP per interface, but it's possible to have several via IP aliasing.

Individual connections on each IP address are identified by port number. There is a limit of 65536 ports per IP address imposed by the IP protocol. One reason behind IP aliasing is to overcome this limitation.

Comment: so what will be the answer to the question? is it 188.37.22.157?